# System requirements running blockchain application

Tags: dapps, hardware

From an IT/infrastructure perspective (im not a developer) what are the system requirements to run a fully functioning blockchain application i.e based on ethereum for a small - medium sized business. How do you host the application i.e AWS? I will be starting as sys admin so will need to deploy everything for the company. Is there a guide available where i can find this. Thanks